# Overriding method with composition

Tags: java, composition

Consider following situation. I want to achieve the different behavior for `methoddA()` of `class A` depending upon from where it is getting call like here from `class D` or `class C`. How this can be achieved, method overriding is not working here.

```
class A
{
    public methodA(){ //some code }
}

class B
{
    A a = new A()
    public methodB()
    {
        a.methodA(); 
    }
}

class C
{
    B b = new B();

    public methodC()
    {
        b.methodB();
    }
}

class D
{
    B b = new B();

    public methodD()
    {
        b.methodB();
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of different behavior you want to achieve?

Comment: may be some different code in case if called from class C and some different code if called from class D.

Comment: why you want this? if you want different behaviour depends where function is called, maybe you can just call different method?

Comment: Sounds like dynamic dispatch, perhaps a [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can help in this case, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is Polymorphism. First create an interface -

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    void methodA();
}
```

then create two different implementations for two different behaviors -

```
public class First implements MyInterface
{
    public void methodA() {
        // first behavior
    }
}

public class Second implements MyInterface
{
    public void methodA() {
        // second behavior
    }
}
```

Now create your other classes as follows -

```
class B
{
    public void methodB(MyInterface m)
    {
        m.methodA(); 
    }
}

class C
{
    B b = new B();

    public void methodC()
    {
        // Pass the corresponding behavior implementation
        // as argument here.
        b.methodB(new First());
    }
}

class D
{
    B b = new B();

    public void methodD()
    {
        // Pass the second behavior implementation.
        b.methodB(new Second());
    }
}
```

This will result in a more maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the class name to your method as a String and in your method check

```
if(className.equals("A") // or use isInstanceOf() if you are passing objects of A/B
//do something

if(className.equals("B")
// do something else.
```

Why do you need two different implementations?
This easy trick can work for you... Please correct me if i am wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I following code I have modified the method signature of Class A1 and Class B1 to accept Object and similarly while calling the methods from Class C and Class D whereever we are calling this method of class B1 pass this as reference. In Class A1 we can then check instanceof object and identify the calling class.

```
class A1
{
    public void methodA(Object c){ //some code }
        if (D.class.isInstance(c)){
            System.out.println("Called from Class D");
        }else if (C.class.isInstance(c)){
            System.out.println("Called from Class c");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Called from Some diff class");
        }
    }

}

class B1
{
    A1 a = new A1();
    public void methodB(Object c)
    {
        a.methodA(c); 
    }
}

class C
{
    B1 b = new B1();

    public void methodC()
    {
        b.methodB(this);
    }
}

class D
{
    B1 b = new B1();

    public void methodD()
    {
        b.methodB(this);
    }
}


public class Testnew{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        D d = new D();
        d.methodD();

        C c = new C();
        c.methodC();

        B1 b = new B1();
        b.methodB(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: The use of `instanceof` in this way is, almost always, a code smell. There are better design alternatives.